# Is it possible to get a list of workflows of current user in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

How to get a list of active workflows/tasks of current user in Alfresco by JavaScript API ?

It is require to create a rule which will write active tasks to the some file and hang/attach this rule to/on a folder.

Comment: Won't [workflow.getAssignedTasks()](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/API-JS-WorkflowManager-getAssignedTasks.html) give you what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get the list of workflows.
You can do that with the following api.

```
GET /alfresco/service/api/task-instances?authority={authority?}&state={state?}&priority={priority?}&pooledTasks={pooledTasks?}&dueBefore={dueBefore?}&dueAfter={dueAfter?}&properties={properties?}&maxItems={maxItems?}&skipCount={skipCount?}&exclude={exclude?}

GET /alfresco/service/api/workflow-instances/{workflow_instance_id}/task-instances?authority={authority?}&state={state?}&priority={priority?}&dueBefore={isoDate?}&dueAfter={isoDate?}&properties={prop1, prop2, prop3...?}&maxItems={maxItems?}&skipCount={skipCount?}&exclude={exclude?}
```

Note: You can set your own parameters according to your requirements in the request

See the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/references/API-JS-WorkflowService.html).

Comment: I know about RESTful but it is not a JavaScript API.